# Objective C NonNull?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have

```
- (void)runSomeMethod:(nullable id<SomeProtocol>)someProtocol {
  id<SomeProtocol> someProtocolLocal = someProtocol;
  if(someProtocolLocal != nil){
    [self runSomeMethodTwo:someProtocolLocal];
  }
}

- (void)runSomeMethodTwo:(id<SomeProtocol>)someProtocol { //notice its not nullable here
  // ...
}
```

This above compiles **fine** by converting `someProtocol` param into `someProtocolLocal` in `runSomeMethod`, however, is this the right way to do it? If I don't create the local variable I get a builder issue saying I'm passing nullable into non-null.

Comment: If passing a `nil` object does nothing, why do you allow it in the first place?

Comment: I am not super certain, but I would assume that — because of the way things were in ObjC for decades — `nullable` would be default, so your second method would be nullable as-well.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Nah, there is `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL` in all Obj-C templates by default.